# Rails Paperclip undefined method `image_files_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm trying trying to upload a file via Paperclip, but I'm getting an error i don't understand:

```
undefined method `image_files_path'
```

The evil Code (Line 2) is

```
<h1>File Upload</h1>
<% form_for(@imageFile,:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.label 'Photo' %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in routes.rb

```
resources :image_files
```

Comment: Thanks that helped! But all I'm getting now... actually nothing! '<body><h1>File Upload</h1></body>' that's all... Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: could you please describe briefly how did you install paperclip (workflow) ? by editing you answer